# TableLayoutPanel column won't occupy 100% width

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have an issue with `TableLayoutPanel`. Despite using a single column with 100% width, the control I add keeps the size assigned to it in layout creator.

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = someTableLayoutPanel;

panel.RowStyles.Clear();
panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
panel.Controls.Clear();

ColumnStyle columnStyle = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F);
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(columnStyle);

int count = capabilityListManager.DeviceCount();

panel.RowCount = deviceCount;
panel.ColumnCount = 1;

for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
{
    RowStyle rowStyle = new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 120F);
    panel.RowStyles.Add(rowStyle);

    SomeCustomControl cell = new SomeCustomControl();
    panel.Controls.Add(cell, 0, index);
}
```

I assumed that would be enough for the control to always be resized to have fixed 120 pixels height and take 100% of width provided by `TableLayoutPanel`, however the result looks like this:

[image]

My custom control is the one with the border, and the `TableLayoutPanel` has blueish hue - clearly there's space left for the control to occupy.

`SomeCustomControl` has its `AutoSize` property set to `false`. What am I missing?

Comment: `SizeType.Percent, 100F` defines the Cell's Width in relation to the TLP.Width. If you add another Column with `SizeType.Percent, 100F`, both Columns will be automatically set to 50% of the TLP.Width, filling the TLP.Width. If you want your UC to occupy the whole Cell, dock it to Fill. Or set the TLP to AutoSize (so both dimensions are determined by the content).

Comment: `Dock` was indeed the issue, although setting it to `Fill` makes the cell occupy the entire `TableLayoutPanel` ignoring row height. Setting it to `Top` fixed the issue.

Comment: Well, you set the Cell Height to a fixed value... Note that you can fine-tune the Cell's dimensions using the UC,s `Margin` Property, which will add an *invisible border* around the Control.